# Closed form for a sum of product of Modified Bessel Functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form, bessel-functions

Let's consider the sum
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}nI_{n}(ax)K_{n}(bx)$$
Here $I_{n}$ and $K_{n}$ are the modified Bessel functions of the first and second kind respectively and $b>a>0$ are real constants.

Using the asymptotics for $n\to +\infty$ for the Bessel functions I proved that the sum converges $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$. I would like to know if a closed form exists.

Without the $n$ I would have used the summation formula, but in this case I can't think of anything helpful. Thanks in advance.

Edit: Following Gary advice, I substituted the product $I_{n}K_{n}$ with the integral. Then interchanged the integral and sum obtaining
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-(b-a)x\cosh{t}}\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(n+1)J_{2n+2}(2\sqrt{ab}x\sinh{t})d t$$

If i am not mistaken if I have the sum $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_{n\nu}J_{\nu+2n+1}$ it holds that
$$a_{n\nu}=2(\nu+2n+1)\int_{0}^{+\infty}u^{-1}f(u)J_{\nu+2n+1}(u)du.$$
Here $\nu=1$ and $a_{n}=n+1$ and the condition becomes
$$\frac{1}{4}=\int_{0}^{+\infty}u^{-1}f(u)J_{2n+2}(u)du,$$
which is a bit weird, because I have to find a function whose integral against every $J_{2n+2}$ is independant on $n$. Maybe the answer is trivial.

Comment: If you use $I_n (ax)K_n (bx) = \int_0^{ + \infty } {J_{2n} (2\sqrt {ab} x\sinh t)e^{ - (b - a)x\cosh t} dt}$, you have to sum a Neumann series. I am not sure if this helps. This is formula $(78)$ on p. $98$ of *Higher Transcendental Functions Vol. II* by Erdélyi et al.

Comment: @Gary I edited my question with some ideas developed from your comment